# SQL data type for variable list of integers

Tags: mysql

I am newbie to SQL.

What I have learned so far is that we have SET as data type which stores the list of values but the  entries in the SET are pre-defined.

```
CREATE TABLE myset (col SET('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
```

In my problem, I dont know what values would come during my way.

I want a table something like:

```
  DeviationInfoID   Value
  1             5, 6
  2             5930, 5561
```

Values in the column "Value" is not pre-defined.

Please suggest some data type for Value column of my table.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Suppose you have sort input, so you can use `VARCHAR(text_limit)`

Comment: This depends on what you want to use the data for. You could always just store it as a string, if you're not going to need to access individual elements via queries.

Comment: Inputs are not sorted and moreover, I need to access individual items as well.

Comment: Do not store comma separated values in a single column. Read up on database normalization and an 1:many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can tack `text` datatype for your `value` coloumn

Comment: Ok. But then text is a string. To fetch individual items, I need to do some text parsing. Isn't there any datatype, which would provide me an iterator over the values ?

Comment: @user3758647 I think no! please read comment of a_horse_with_no_name. Process your strings first & then insert in database in normalized way.